# In Angular why will my Dynamic Tabs / Tab Panes work initially but not after update?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, core-ui

I am currently using version 3.4 of CoreUI for my Angular App and I am attempting to use their Tabs setup.

Currently it works fine if I populate the tabs oninit but if I update them it breaks. The entire purpose of being able to use this is to have a dynamic list of tabs and content in those tabs so I am at a loss for why this wouldn't work.

I made a very dumbed down version below to show what I am trying. Note that the first instance of this._tabs works fine, after my await calls when I update to the second version it fails to display correctly.

HTML

```html
<c-card>
  <c-card-header>
    Tabs <code><small>nav-underline</small></code>
  </c-card-header>
  <c-card-body>
    <c-tabset class="nav-underline nav-underline-primary">
      <c-tablist>
        <c-tab *ngFor="let tab of tabs"  >
          {{tab.header}}
        </c-tab>
      </c-tablist>
      <c-tab-content>
        <br>
        <c-tab-pane *ngFor="let tab of tabs">
          <p>
            {{tab.panel}}
          </p>
        </c-tab-pane>
      </c-tab-content>
    </c-tabset>
  </c-card-body>
</c-card>
```

Component

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { DbService, DashCpResult, IssuerGroup } from '../../db.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.scss']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  // Arrays
  DashCpResults: Array<DashCpResult>;

  private _setTab: number;
  get setTab() {
    return this._setTab;
  }
  set setTab(value: number) {
    this._setTab = value || 0;
  }

  private _tabs: any[] = [];

  public get tabs() {
    return this._tabs;
  }


  constructor(
    private DbService: DbService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
  ) {
    this.setTab = 0;
  }

  rungetDashCpResult(id) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
    this.DbService.getDashCpResult(id).subscribe(DashCpResults => this.DashCpResults = DashCpResults,
      (err) => { 
        console.log('ERROR: ' + JSON.stringify(err)); 
    },() => {
    resolve(1);
    });
    })
    }
    

  async ngOnInit() {
    this._tabs = [
      { header: 'Home', panel: 'Home'},
      { header: 'Home2', panel: 'Home2'},
      { header: 'Home3', panel: 'Home3'},
      { header: 'Home4', panel: 'Home4'}

    ];

    // Get Screen detail for Tabs
    try { await this.rungetDashCpResult(1); } catch (e) {console.log(e)}
    // Update Tabs for a test
    this._tabs = [
      { header: 'Home5', panel: 'Home5'},
      { header: 'Home6', panel: 'Home6'},
      { header: 'Home7', panel: 'Home7'},
      { header: 'Home8', panel: 'Home8'}

    ];
    }
  }
```

Comment: We can't reproduce this since we don't know what `DbService`, `DashCpResult`, and `IssuerGroup` are. Please provide a reproducible example.